# Display data returned with Ajax in table format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax+Jquery to get data from a PHP api. In that PHP api at the last step I do-

$data_enc = json_encode($data);
echo $data_enc;

And I get this returned-

```
{"headers":["Age","Count","Consent","Intent"],"data":{"17":{"Age":"17","Count":2,"Consent":"2","Intent":0},"18":{"Age":"108","Count":3,"Consent":"3","Intent":0},"115":{"Age":"115","Count":1,"Consent":"1","Intent":0},"117":{"Age":"117","Count":2,"Consent":"2","Intent":0},"118":{"Age":"118","Count":1,"Consent":"1","Intent":0},"Totals":{"Age":"Total","Count":67,"Consent":67,"Intent":0}}}
```

On the Jquery side,

```
success: function(data){
    alert(typeof(data)); //returns string
},
```

When I do a typeof(data) in the jQuery Ajax success, it says that its a string.
I need to display this data in a table with columns as Age, Count, Consent, Intent.

I tried looping over the object on the jQuery side but couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Do you use `dataType: "json",` in your ajax call ?

Comment: Parse JSON using `JSON.parse()`! There's no data type for JSON.

Comment: "It says its a string", "I tried looping over the object".  string != object.  Your first google should have been, "how do I convert json to an object?"

Comment: @VincentDecaux I used that but it errored out, which makes me think again about what **Taplar** said, that I'm getting a string and not an object. But wouldn't doing a json_encode make it a JSON object?

Comment: @manishk you want to use JSON.parse(jsonData) function -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I was missing something totally gnarly with my code. Have rectified that now. Thank you though, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataType: 'json' in your ajax request.

To build the table:

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '...',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (result) {
       $('#myTable tr').empty();
       var header = $('#myTable thead');
       var body = $('#myTable tbody');
       var hTr;
       $('#myTable thead').append(hTr = $('<tr>'));
       // Headers
       for (var h = 0; h < result.headers.length; h++) {
          hTr.append($('<th>', { text: result.headers[h] }))
       }
       // Body
       for (var d in result.data) {
          var data = result.data[d];
          $('#myTable tbody').append($('<tr>')
              .append($('<td>', { text: data.Age }))
              .append($('<td>', { text: data.Count }))
              .append($('<td>', { text: data.Consent }))
              .append($('<td>', { text: data.Intent }))
          )
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: You are missing braces- 
.append($('<td>', { text: data.Age }))
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Another question- When I send the request multiple times, the data is getting appended in the table (the <tr> and <td>). How can I get the table with only the result of the latest request?

Comment: Nevermind, just used $("#myTable tr").remove(); at the top, right inside success.